# One form shared data split into multiple rows

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-forms

I'm looking for ideas on how to save an big survey into multiple rows (MySQL).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am relatively new to python and django programming.

Form:

```
<form method="post">

<label for="InputOD1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Order Number</label>
<input type="text" id="InputOD1" name="InputOD1" placeholder="Order Number">

<label for="InputSA1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Shipping Address</label>
<input type="text" id="InputSA1" name="InputSA1" placeholder="Shipping Address">



<label for="InputFN1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="InputFN1" name="InputFN1" placeholder="Last Name">

<label for="InputLN1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" id="InputLN1" name="InputLN1" placeholder="Last Name">

<label for="InputGR1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gender</label>
<input type="text" id="InputGR1" name="InputGR1" placeholder="Gender>



<label for="InputFN2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="InputFN2" name="InputFN2" placeholder="Last Name">

<label for="InputLN1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" id="InputLN2" name="InputLN2" placeholder="Last Name">

<label for="InputGR1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gender</label>
<input type="text" id="InputGR2" name="InputGR2" placeholder="Gender>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Expected database outcome:

```
Order Number, Shipping Address, First Name 1, Last Name 1, Gender 1
Order Number, Shipping Address, First Name 2, Last Name 2, Gender 2
....
Order Number, Shipping Address, First Name 5, Last Name 5, Gender 5
```

Answer (score 0):

For this task you should use [django formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/).